# Getting uninstall packages offer after package updates

Tags: init-file, package, use-package

Each time I call up `list-package` and update, I get this message after the updates

```
Operation finished.  Packages that are no longer needed: 43.  Type ‘M-x package-autoremove’ to remove them
```

Below is my init.el concerning use-package

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)

(setq package-archives '(("ELPA"  . "http://tromey.com/elpa/")
("gnu"   . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
("org"   . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/")))

(package-initialize)

;;; Bootstrapping use-package, i.e., if use-package isn't installed
;;; then install it
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

;;;This will ensure all packages are installed if not already
(require 'use-package-ensure)
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)

;;;This will make sure packages are updated
(use-package auto-package-update
  :config
  (setq auto-package-update-delete-old-versions t)
  (setq auto-package-update-interval 1)
  (setq auto-package-update-hide-results t)
  (auto-package-update-maybe))
```

I obviously don't want to uninstall all the packages on my system. What have I done wrong? A critique, please.

**Update**

Here's the `package-selected-packages` in my `custom-set-variables`(which is *huge* BTW).

```
'(package-selected-packages
   '(org-journal deft org-roam abyss-theme hindent shm ob-sml sml-mode org-num rdf-prefix ediprolog sparql-mode emacsql-sqlite emacsql-mysql emacsql ess json-mode ac-slime cmake-mode gnuplot flymake-css ac-geiser quack geiser elcord erc-hl-nicks diminish htmlize sudo-edit magit company-shell company-lua company-jedi company-irony company-c-headers flycheck-clang-analyzer company flycheck yasnippet org ox-tufte ox-twbs org-bullets popup-kill-ring zzz-to-char hungry-delete expand-region rainbow-delimiters rainbow-mode beacon mark-multiple avy helm linum-relative swiper switch-window which-key ivy symon fancy-battery spaceline dashboard projectile async pretty-mode zerodark-theme use-package))
```

Comment: I think somehow installing packages stores them in `package-selected-packages`, and then it offers to uninstall anything that's not in that list or a dependency of a package in that list. That variable is saved by the "customize" system. Is it possible you are doing something unusual with `custom-file`?

Comment: Well, I have this: `(setq custom-file "~/.emacs.d/my-custom.el")` then `(load custom-file)` at the end of my `init.el`. This calls my massive `custom-set-variables` expression where `package-selected-packages` is.